# Making my own dua

Tags: dua

I Know in Islam you are allowed to make your own dua's 
But I don't know how. I want to make my own dua but I don't know where to find the right translation to the words I want to say.

Can someone help me out? My parents speak fluent Arabic and can help me 100% But I wan't to try and make it by finding the words myself.

Sincerely  محمد

Answer (score 1):

***Dua*** does not have to be in Arabic. It can be in any language, or in none, meaning you are praying for things/feelings/desires in your heart but cannot or do not translate those in words.

**Allah** knows, in fact created, all languages. He understands all languages. He chose Arabic for offering *Salah* and the language for The Day of Judgement. On that day, everyone will talk in Arabic. But that does not mean that you cannot communicate with Him in any other language, or cry in front of Him in any other language, or make *Dua* to Him in any other language.